# Using older version of support library in one of the dependencies

Tags: android, gradle

Following is the output of app:dependencies

```
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.2.1
|    +--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:23.2.1
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.2.1
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.2.1 (*)
+--- com.android.support:design:23.2.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1
|         +--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1 (*)
|         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.2.1
+--- com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1
+--- project :library
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0 -> 23.2.1 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0 -> 23.2.1 (*)
\--- org.jooq:joor:0.9.5
```

As you can see my library depends on support lib 22.2.0. How can I make my project `library` to use 22.2.0 instead of 23.2.1. My app fails on 23.2.1. Is there a way to compile `library` separately with the older version of support library?

My dependencies looks like this,

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile project(':library')
    compile 'org.jooq:joor:0.9.5' 
}
```

Comment: Why does your lib fail with 23.2.1?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this will help you, but I had a similar problem with a newer library version causing problems, so I forced the old one to be used.

When you define your dependencies, try:

```
    compile('com.android.support:design:22.2.0'){
    force = true
    }

    compile('com.android.support:design:22.2.0') {
    force = true
    }
```

Hopefully this helps.